# Webstorm 11 color scheme messed up when using Textmate Bundle for CJSX

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm, jsx

I have followed this article and the color scheme gets horridly messed up,
the line where I am at is black, but everything else is colored as if it where default, highlighting makes that parts background go blue.

http://www.residue.io/2015/01/30/webstorm-cjsx-support/

[image]

I have followed everything on the instructions and restarted WebStorm, its at a point where I'm considering dropping CJSX or Webstorm, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What editor color scheme do you use? Darcula? Please open `Settings | Editor | TextMate Bundles`, and in the color schemes table shown in the bottom choose the appropriate `TextMate Color Scheme` for your current `IDE Color Scheme`. For example, if your current scheme is Darcula, select it, and choose '**Darcula**' from Textmate schemes popup; then re-open your file in editor to apply a new scheme. If '**Darcula**' doesn't look good enough, try others ('**IR_Black**', for example) - see which one suits you better

Comment: It was Darcula, needed to do 2 things, change the appropirate color scheme AND restart Webstorm, maybe reopening it does it too, but i Though pushing the Apply button would do the trick but it didn't do the job so I panicked..... thank you verymuch